# Extract and count hashtags from a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with some tweets, something like this:

```
tweets = pd.Series(['This is a tweet example #help #thankyou', 
                    'Second tweet example #help', 
                    'Third tweet example #help #stackoverflow'])

tweets_df = pd.DataFrame({'Tweets': tweets})
```

Then I put the hashtags in another column of the dataframe

```
tweets_df['hashtags'] = tweets_df['Tweets'].apply(lambda twt : re.findall(r"#(\w+)", twt))
```

Now I want to count them and put the results in another dataframe. I have tried with the following but didn't worked

```
tweets_df['hashtags'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```

The result must be something like:

```
#help           2
#thankyou       1
#stackoverflow  1
```

Comment: Shouldn't `#help` have `3`?

Answer (score 6):

Let's use `extractall` and `value_counts`:

```
tweets_df.Tweets.str.extractall(r'(\#\w+)')[0].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
#help             3
#stackoverflow    1
#thankyou         1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter(tweets_df.hashtags.sum())
df = pd.DataFrame([d]).T

>>> df
                0
help            3
stackoverflow   1
thankyou        1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make `tweets` into a dataframe. Just perform the extraction from there:

```
tweets.str.extractall(r'(\#\w*)')[0].value_counts()

#help             3
#stackoverflow    1
#thankyou         1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```