# Word counts and Hashtag counts in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with captions and mentions for Instagram posts (below).

```
df[['caption', 'mentions']].sample(7)


  caption                                             mentions
42  b'Alexa is helping people of all abilities do ...   NaN
48  NaN NaN
7   b'Introducing Amazon Pharmacy. :pill::clipboar...   NaN
25  b"When it's day:victory_hand_selector:and the ...   charliesmallsthedood
58  b'We look at all angles when it comes to safet...   NaN
88  b'A night in with your favorite food + pup + e...   amazonfiretv,lissettecalv
22  b'Get everyday essentials auto-delivered AND s...   NaN
```

I want to create two columns:

***unique_word_count:***
I want create a column that counts the unique words in each caption (it would count each emoji as 1 word - format :emoji:). Some of the captions are blank and NaN - those should have a unique word count of zero.

***mention_counts***
I want a column for mention counts that returns number of mentions. In the sample above  it would return (0,0,0,1,0,2,0).

Things I have tried so far:

```
## new column where :emoji: -> X and type string, to more accurately count character and words later
df['caption_for_counts'] = df['caption'].str.replace(r':[^:\s]*(?:::[^:\s]*)*:', "X")
df['caption_for_counts'] = df['caption_for_counts'] .astype(str)


## create column for caption lengeth in characters
df['caption_length'] = df['caption_for_counts'].str.len()

## Split list into new series
captions = df['caption_for_counts'].str.lower().str.split()


df[['caption', 'mentions']].sample(7)

## Get amount of unique words
#df['caption_word_count'] = 0 if captions == 'nan' else captions.apply(set).apply(len)


for item, row in df['caption_word_count'].iteritems():
    if row != 'nan':
        df['caption_unique_words'] = captions.apply(set).apply(len)
    else:
        df['caption_unique_words'] = 0


## Get amount of words
#df['caption_word_count'] = 0 if captions.empty else captions.apply(len)

for item, row in df['caption_word_count'].iteritems():
    if row != 'nan':
        df['caption_word_count'] = captions.apply(len)
    else:
        df['caption_word_count'] = 0


## number of hashtags

df

df.dtypes
## number of mentions
df['mentions_for_counts'] = df['mentions'] .astype(str)
mentions = df['mentions_for_counts'].str.lower().str.split(',')



for value in df['mentions_for_counts']:
    if value != 'nan':
        df['mention_counts'] = mentions.apply(len)
    else:
        df['mention_counts'] = 0



df['number_of_mentions'] = mentions.apply(sum)
```

enter code here

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @LeonardusChen I updated with what I have tried. The main issue I have is handling the NaNs

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but maybe still useful.

Code to extract and count the hashtags per row and tweet (each tweet is stored in a separate row in a dataframe).

```
#extract hashtags and put in a new column 
%timeit df['hashtags'] = df['text'].str.findall(r'(#(?:[^\x00-\x7F]|\w)+)')
2.17 ms ± 17.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#alternative solution to extract hashtags and put in new column with apply
%timeit df['hashtags'] = df['text'].apply(lambda twt : re.findall(r"(#(?:[^\x00-\x7F]|\w)+)", twt))
3.68 ms ± 10.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

#count number of hashtags per row (tweet) and put in a new column
%timeit df['hashtagCount']  = df.hashtags.agg([len])
1.11 ms ± 73.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

In case a dictionary of all the different hashtags used in the dataset including their frequency count is needed, below a solution:

```
from collections import Counter
d = Counter(df.hashtags.sum())
```

Else see [this post for more dictionary frequency count solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49865756/extract-and-count-hashtags-from-a-dataframe).