# Performatic way to count hashtags inside list (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, list, count, hashtag

I have a dataframe with ~7.000.000 rows and a lot of columns.

Each row is a Tweet, and i have a column **text** with tweet's content.

I created a new column just for hashtags inside text:

```py
df['hashtags'] = df.Tweets.str.findall(r'(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))#.*?(?=\s|$)')
```

So i have a column called **hashtags** with each row containing a list structure: `['#b747', '#test']`.

I would like to **count the number of each hashtag** but i have a heavy number of rows. What is the most performatic way to do it?

Comment: Not sure if it's most performant. But one option could be `df.hashtags.explode().value_counts()`

Comment: @Psidom: this is probably one of the most performant approaches. It is also the most natural one I can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some different approaches, along with timing, ordered by speed (fastest first):

```py
# setup
n = 10_000
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'hashtags': np.random.randint(0, int(np.sqrt(n)), (n, 10)).astype(str).tolist(),
})


# 1. using itertools.chain to build an iterator on the elements of the lists
from itertools import chain
%timeit Counter(chain(*df.hashtags))
# 7.35 ms ± 58.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


# 2. as per @Psidom comment
%timeit df.hashtags.explode().value_counts()
# 8.06 ms ± 19.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


# 3. using Counter constructor, but specifying an iterator, not a list
%timeit Counter(h for hl in df.hashtags for h in hl)
# 10.6 ms ± 13.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


# 4. iterating explicitly and using Counter().update()
def count5(s):
    c = Counter()
    for hl in s:
        c.update(hl)
    return c
%timeit count5(df.hashtags)
# 12.4 ms ± 66.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


# 5. using itertools.reduce on Counter().update()
%timeit reduce(lambda x,y: x.update(y) or x, df.hashtags, Counter())
# 13.7 ms ± 10.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


# 6. as per @EzerK
%timeit Counter(sum(df['hashtags'].values, []))
# 2.58 s ± 1.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Conclusion: the fastest is #1 (using `Counter(chain(*df.hashtags))`), but the more intuitive and natural #2 (from @Psidom comment) is almost as fast. I would probably go with that. #6 (@EzerK approach) is very slow for large `df` slow because we are building a new (long) list before passing it as argument to `Counter()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can all the lists to one big list and then use collections.Counter:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['hashtags'] = [['#b747', '#test'], ['#b747', '#test']]

Counter(sum(df['hashtags'].values, []))
```

Comment: will be extraordinarily slow on a large `df`.

Answer (score 0):

Tried solutions 1, 2 and 3 from Pierre's answer as they are most performant and I wanted one or two lines of code. Also I wanted to have the count of hashtags per tweet, i.e. per row, and not a dictionary of all the different hashtags used in the dataset including their frequency count. An up-vote from me for all the effort and different methods Pierre suggests.

Unfortunately, solutions 1, 2 and 3 all returned NaNs for the Twitter data I work with. Also tried different variants of `tweets_df.Tweets.str.extractall(r'(\#\w+)')[0].value_counts()` suggested  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49865756/extract-and-count-hashtags-from-a-dataframe) but none of them worked.

What worked in the end are these two lines

```
%timeit df['hashtags'] = df['text'].str.findall(r'(?:(?<=\s)|(?<=^))#.*?(?=\s|$)')
15.2 ms ± 212 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit df['hashtagCount']  = df.hashtags.agg([len])
1.11 ms ± 73.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

On the note of performance, this code to extract hashtags uses less time:

```
#alternative solution to extract hashtags and put in new column with apply
%timeit df['hashtags'] = df['text'].apply(lambda twt : re.findall(r"(#(?:[^\x00-\x7F]|\w)+)", twt))
3.68 ms ± 10.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```